# VUE-CHART this.renderChart is not a function

Tags: vue.js, vue-chartjs

I'm trying to make a chart in Vue.js but I'm getting this error all the time:

**Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this.renderChart is not a function**

Here is my code:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <canvas ref="donutChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { Doughnut } from 'vue-chartjs';

export default {
  extends: Doughnut,
  name: 'donut',
  mounted() {
    const chartData = {
      labels: ['Red', 'Green', 'Blue'],
      datasets: [
        {
          backgroundColor: ['#FF5733', '#33FF57', '#3380FF'],
          data: [25, 30, 45]
        }
      ]
    };

    const chartOptions = {
      responsive: true,
      maintainAspectRatio: false
    };

    this.renderChart(chartData, chartOptions);
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using V4 or V5 of vue-chart.js. The syntax has been changed as noted in their [migration guide](https://vue-chartjs.org/migration-guides/).

Instead of calling `this.renderChart()` you have to directly insert the actual component in the template:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <Doughnut
      :data="chartData"
      :options="chartOptions"
      ref="donutChart"
      :width="400"
      :height="400"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { Doughnut } from 'vue-chartjs';

export default {
  name: 'donut',
  data() {
    chartData: {
      labels: ['Red', 'Green', 'Blue'],
      datasets: [
        {
          backgroundColor: ['#FF5733', '#33FF57', '#3380FF'],
          data: [25, 30, 45]
        }
      ]
    },
    chartOptions: {
      responsive: true,
      maintainAspectRatio: false
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Possible duplicate of [73430545](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73430545/uncaught-in-promise-typeerror-this-renderchart-is-not-a-function-vuejs-chart).